# Short story where administrator candidates are tested on a miniature society

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short science fiction story about a future where administrators testing for a new position had to test themselves on a miniature, accelerated world. For a low level position, it might be 15 minutes, while a regional governor might be several hours.

The population of this miniature world lived at an accelerated pace, perhaps years every minute and the actions of the testee would affect a town, a region or even the entire world. If too many of the citizens died, the small electrical charge in their spines would feedback into the testee and cause damage or even death of the testee.

The story then follows one of the little citizens who hears about the "new god" (the testee) and decides to follow this new god, who seems complacent compared to previous "gods".

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall when you read this?  Was it online, in an anthology or a magazine?

Comment: This has been asked before. Now to find the duplicate ...

Comment: [This is the previous question I remembered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34952/short-story-in-which-candidates-for-political-office-act-as-deities-to-tiny-syn). The story is [The Short Ones](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40946) by Raymond E. Banks. Does this seem like it fits your description?

Comment: [Possibly also this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255517/short-story-about-candidates-for-president-they-are-connected-to-a-god-game).

Comment: Yes, This is exactly the story and looking at its publication history, I probably read it in The Bootcamp 3000 anthology. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14):

This is exactly ["The Short Ones" by Raymond E. Banks](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40946).

The story is told in the third person alternating between two viewpoints.

The first is the man running for political office who must undergo the test controlling the two-inch-tall artificial people. A description of another candidate tearing off the test helmet as his brain is damaged from electrical shock is in the story. This is the risk the protagonist takes.

It alternates with a third-person account of the artificial people. Every new candidate is the new "god". An information (or perhaps power-supply) wire is called by the little people -- the "Short Ones"-- the "god-wire".

The candidate does have the power to kill them to control them. Since killing too many people to keep them controlled is a characteristic of a dangerous tyrant, any candidate taking the test is at this risk of frying his brain if he overloads the system by killing too many people. A societal riot in the artificial people is of course another disqualifier of the political candidate.

The story involves mainly the protagonist candidate, and his life and failing marriage, and one of the Short Ones who is trying to communicate with, and satisfy, this new "god".

The Short Ones have wars between the "priests" -- the one who communicate with the current "god". Our human protagonist helps a murdered artifical Short One just before he dies, by killing the murdering rival artificial "priest".

And yes, reading the comments after this answer, as John Rennie commented, I am certain it is the story with [this description](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255517/short-story-about-candidates-for-president-they-are-connected-to-a-god-game).

Comment: Yes, this is the story I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! You can check the check mark as "yes, found the answer".